# iPhone realtime messaging

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm going to do a simple app similar to Apple WiTap example. The purpose of it is sending a small text message between two devices.
The user with the first device writes and push over 'Invia (send)' button. Once done, the message will appear on second device with an alert.
How could I implement the string sending-and-receiving part in my project?
The wip source is located here: http://bit.ly/fYAQsb
Thank you.

Comment: Are Push notifications an option with a push server?

Comment: No, I cannot use Push Notifications. I want only use simple UIAlert to view messages and UITextView + UIButton for sending.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PubNub to send and receive messages, completely bypassing APNS.

Quick start and tutorials can be found here: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/ios-sdk.html